# Genexus Uploadify not working with large files

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, genexus

I have a website made in Genexus with a transaction which includes a Uploadify control in it, running on a local Tomcat server, and it works fine with small files but when I try to upload a bigger one (> 50 MB) it appears to upload the file but then returns to the transaction screen.

I ran a test using Developer Tools included in Google Chrome, and I noticed that, when I try to upload large files, a "500 - Internal Server Error" occurs. Clicking on the corresponding line in the "Network" tab gives this:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.DefaultFileItem.cleanup()V
at com.genexus.webpanels.HttpContextWeb.cleanup(Unknown Source)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectBase.doExecute(Unknown Source)
at br.com.procempa.spm.cauge.texpedientessoliceventosalter.doExecute(texpedientessoliceventosalter.java:21)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(Unknown Source)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:420)
at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doPost(InvokerServlet.java:170)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(Unknown Source)
com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(Unknown Source)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:420)
org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doPost(InvokerServlet.java:170)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.28 logs.

Apache Tomcat/5.5.28
```

Searching on some websites, I found suggestions to edit the application's web.xml adding the following tag inside the <servlet> tag in tomcat-directory/application-directory/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<multipart-config>
    <max-file-size>1073741824</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>1073741824</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

And then edited tomcat-directory/conf/server.xml to make the Connector tag for port 8080 look like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="4096" maxPostSize="1073741824"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="600000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

And then restarted Tomcat, but yet it gives me the same error. Am I missing anything else?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Actually, my application is a Java one, and the control used is not a true "Uploadify", it has class "Image" and is linked to a BLOB field in the database. Isn't it the case to change the field type in the transaction form?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your form the Uploadify property "Size Limit".

In web.config check `maxRequestLength` in `<system.web>` and the `requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength` in `<security>`.

Example:

```
<system.web>
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="50000"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
   <hiddenSegments>
    <add segment="PrivateTempStorage" />
    <add segment="private" />
   </hiddenSegments>
   <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000"/>
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```